# Storing the return value from a function in a SSIS package variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, ssis

I would like to use execute SQL step to  `select function_name()` that returns a value of data type `decimal(16,4)`  and store it in an SSIS variable and then use that variable and pass it as a parameter to a SP in the following step. However, when I am doing this and executing the steps, the output is always coming as 0, I am guessing the either the way I had set up my variables is bad or I am not passing it correctly, can someone please help!!!

Comment: Where is your code??!! Please edit your question and add the Sql code. :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the SSIS Execute SQL task and pay careful attention to the parameter mapping and result set tabs. Please read this to see how to map the input and output correctly:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280502.aspx#Return_codes

It takes a bit of time (typically more then a minute and less then an hour) to get it to work.

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-execute-sql-task-to-generate-result-sets/

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this in TSQL like so...

```
DECALRE @fnResult DECIMAL(16,4)

SET @fnResult = dbo.UFn_getSaleDollar()

EXEC someProcedure @procVariable = @fnResult
```

Comment: I can, but the function and SP are on totally different servers, so I need to  do it in a 2 step process - load the result into a variable an then use that variable for my next step

Comment: Why not use a linked server and call it directly? Are you using SSIS just for this step or is this a step in a larger package doing many things? If it is not the latter, then you don't really need SSIS.

Comment: Plus, I am having trouble with the data type of the variable, I do not see a decimal under the ssis  package variable datatypes, any idea??

Comment: It is just a step in a larger package

Comment: I cannot use a liked server to that server, that's against our policy

Comment: @Leoo change the policy. I'm kidding, I try and stay away from SSIS but i'm sure someone else will be able to help you.